# Class Softon\Indipay\Gateways\Gateway does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Getting this issue while implementing Cc-avenue payment gateway with laravel.

> Issue: Class Softon\Indipay\Gateways\Gateway does not exist

[Reference](https://github.com/softon/indipay)

```php
$parameters = ['tid' => '1233221223322', 'order_id' => '1232212', 'amount' => '1200.00',];
// gateway = CCAvenue / PayUMoney / EBS / Citrus / InstaMojo / ZapakPay / Mocker
$order = Indipay::gateway('CCAvenue')->prepare($parameters);
return Indipay::process($order);
```

I have follow all steps given in above ref.

Comment: Please add what you have already tried. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: have you pass parameter `$order = Indipay::gateway('NameOfGateway')->prepare($parameters);`

you should place the appropriate NameOFGateway here

Comment: My code: 

$parameters = [
      
            'tid' => '1233221223322',
            
            'order_id' => '1232212',
            
            'amount' => '1200.00',
            
          ];
          
          // gateway = CCAvenue / PayUMoney / EBS / Citrus / InstaMojo / ZapakPay / Mocker
          
          $order = Indipay::gateway('CCAvenue')->prepare($parameters);
          return Indipay::process($order);

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya: Please check above code

Answer (score 0):

It seems gateway configurations are not passing to "/vendor/softon/indipay/src/IndipayServiceProvider.php"

Please check whether "config.php" is cached or not. You can check it in "bootstrap/cache/config.php". Delete this file and check, I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine on my local development system (Windows) but was not working on my production server (Ubuntu - case sensitive).

I finally had to create a copy of **PayUMoneyGateway.php** file at *websiteroot\vendor\softon\indipay\src* .

The new file name is **payumoneyGateway.php** [G is capital].

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. I was using payumoney gateway. while referring the name of gateway, we have to check the case also(lower and uppercase)

'gateway' => 'PayUMoney',

instead i wrote  'gateway' => 'Payumoney', so it was giving me error. And this issue came in server.

```
// gateway = CCAvenue / PayUMoney / EBS / Citrus / InstaMojo / ZapakPay / Mocker
```

write it in the same way given here